# factory pattern or dependency injection for future implementation

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, factory-pattern

I need to write a program to read content from text files. The format of the text file could be different. For example, the width of the first column could be 20 characters for format A, but 40 characters for format B. The first line of the text file contains the format type. There could be new formats with different column width in future. I'm thinking of using factory pattern, but I'm not sure if using DI can make it easier. What is the best design/architecture recommended in this scenario? The code might have the following interfaces:

```
public interface IFormat
{
    int columnAWidth{ get; }
}

public interface IFormatFactory
{
    IFormat GetFormat(string formatType);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Dependency Injection is not mutually exclusive from the Factory pattern, or any pattern for that matter. You should always aim to reduce coupling in your code for maximum re-usability.

To answer your question it sounds like the Factory Method pattern would suit your needs. Your concrete class definitions could even be read in from xml configuration files.